# Preventing drawing concave polygons

Tags: java, draw, concave

I'm looking for a criterion I can set, when the position of the mouse doesn't meet it, the point cannot be set.

How to prevent drawing a concave polygon in java?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if all you polygon's points are on the convex hull. See for example [Graham Scan](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/99hull/GrahamScan.java.html). It's a class with a constructor which takes an array of `Point2D` objects. A method `hull()` returns an `Iterable<Point2D>`. For every new candidate point for your polygon this iterable must contain your new point.